# error while reading SQL server database when a different database on the same server is restoring

Tags: sql-server, restore

We are running stored procedures from a 'central' SQL server database **A** that reads data from a different database **B** on the same SQL server (SQL Server 2019 Standard edition). Yet, meanwhile another database **C** on that same server is restoring (not the one we are reading from) and sometimes (not always) we receive the error: **"Database 'C' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore."**

Thus, while executing a stored procedure on A selecting data from B, we receive the error that C is restoring...

Note that all of the mentioned databases reside on different files.

Any solutions to avoid this issue?

Comment: It's almost certainly the case that some kind of reference to `C` is present that you're not seeing. Check for synonyms and views that contain references to linked objects, triggers, dynamic `USE` statements, a quirk in the application logic, something. The engine will not, on its own, come up with an unnecessary access to a database that isn't used in the queries -- if you could reliably reproduce that you should probably file a bug report.

Comment: There is by no means a reference to database C in the select stored procedure. It launches a dynamically composed select statement using the "from DB.schema.table" syntax instead of a USE statement.


                                            It will not be possible to reproduce the issue reliably: we have about 60 of these processes going on overnight while only a couple of them fail, with different ones failing on different days, like it is hitting some kind of threshold or limitation.

Comment: @Matthias I agree with Jeroen's comment. It is not possible to receive that error without somehow referencing database `C` or an object that belongs to `C`, either directly or indirectly. But it may be happening in a place you're not expecting / looking, based on the fact it's intermittent. The only advice I'd have is to provide the definition of the stored procedures (or any other SQL code where this issue occurs about) in your original post, and we may be able to speculate on the odd scenario that could be occuring that's resulting in a reference to the offline database.

Comment: Check database level triggers also, and check for synonyms. Without showing us any relevant code, it's hard for us to help